# macOS window is not visible (but is present)

Tags: macos

I'm trying to run VirtualDJ 2021 but whenever I open the application, the window GUI is not visible whatsoever. When I go into mission control, a border appears around the window but there is just a giant block of nothing in it (transparent). I'm using a 2010 MacBook Pro 15" running macOS 10.14.4. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by updating from 10.14.4 to 10.14.6. Make sure to run "macOS Post Install" from a bootable dosdude1 Mojave Installer if using an unsupported device.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly won't help at all that you're running an unsupported OS on your Mac. if the app makes heavy use of Metal2 then results will be at best unpredictable.

The reason your Mac should have stayed on High Sierra is precisely because it doesn't have Metal2 support.

Comment: From what I read, VirtualDJ doesn't use Metal and would still run on High Sierra if needed, so I'm not sure if this suits the reason.

Comment: You're in uncharted territory, you're running an OS that is not supported by your hardware. Only people with similarly compromised machines would even be able to attempt reproduce the issue. Test on High Sierra & see what happens.

Comment: Fixed it by updating to macOS 10.14.6. Turns out that it wasn't a Metal issue at all.

Comment: Glad it worked out :)